# how to prevent landing page from scrolling?

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress website with landing page and content following after. My problem is that I have no clue how to make the landing page not scrollable. My goal is for the additional content only to show after clicking on the arrow at the bottom of the landing page. any tips or suggestions plz? my website is saltwonder.m-arina.com

Comment: How will a user see your content if it doesn't scroll?

Comment: @DanielTheman added a bit more info

Comment: do you want your content hidden until they click the arrow? Something like this collapse: https://codepen.io/danitome24/pen/wBJAd

Comment: not collapse. just simply hidden until the arrow is clicked and it scrolls down to the content.

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: yes. but how can i put it in wordpress?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234708/discussion-between-daniel-theman-and-arina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your first section which you want to show full screen or other too. Then you should use `height:100vh;`.